# Image broken with 4 monitors, but everything works with 1,2 or 3

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor, macbook-pro, external-monitor

I have a macbook pro 2015 set up running linux natively. Through this I have 3 monitors plugged in.

2x Thunderbolt
1x HDMI
1x Laptop Monitor.

If I have 3 monitors the image is as expected. However whenever I plug in a new monitor to equal 4 monitors active in total, the "tearing" starts to play up.

What I find even more confusing is that the background image is perfectly fine and the only issue seems to be the windows/taskbar etc.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can Ubuntu supported as many monitor in a same computer? That's the question

Comment: Interesting, well the display shows it. I will add it to the question showing the monitors.

Comment: I see something really obvious but true here : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1565945 

did you consult how many monitor can support your graphical card?

Comment: The thing is, I have seen it working. With 4, in this exact set up.

Comment: Which connector is the last monitor on? Have you tried switching the order and ports in which you plug in the monitors? (Maybe you have a problem with that specific port/monitor)

Comment: I'll try tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: So switching the order does little. Sadly, there is no problem with any set up, the only problem is having 4 monitors connected. This is also the second machine I have had this problem with. The first being my Razer Blade.

Comment: According to the MacBook Pro 2015 [specs](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs-2015/), the integrated Intel Iris Pro Graphics "Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays". May I ask where you have seen this exact setup work? Maybe we can figure it out when we know how somebody else did it. My guess is that one monitor was connected via a USB3->HDMI/DP/... adapter.

Comment: I saw it working with my setup :) I realise I should have given more information too... A key bit of information potentially, I am using a Dell external Unit which plugs in Via USB 3.0 and has external monitor displays too. `Display Link`